# Cannot "Build All" subreports in Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport, jaspersoft-studio

I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.3.1.final and I have a report with 15 subreports embeded in the main report in this way:

```
<subreport>    
<reportElement x="0" y="320" width="1000" height="20" uuid="504fbc60-0036-46a1-9a04-d42bda10a85f"/>
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["BSR015_17_eu_roamed_text.jasper"]]>            
</subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

When I open the main report and click "Project -> Build All" (or press Ctrl+B) it compiles only the main report and does not compile subreports (it does not create *.jasper files).

When I open each of them and compile individualy then it works well.

Is there any way to compile all subreports at the same time?

Thank you and kind regards

Pawel

Comment: I have also seen this "bug", a workaround is to use "Project>>Clean" it will also build all. Currently however I can't the logs to understand why "Build All" is not launched.

Comment: Thanks @PetterFriberg. In 5.5.1.final your workaround seems to work sometimes somehow.